# How to get multiple attachments from gmail and save them to the folder?

Tags: c#, gmail-api

I am trying to get attachments from a mail and saving them to the folder of my choice. When a mail contains a single attachment, this saves to my folder perfectly regardless of the file type but if a mail contains multiple attachments, only the first attachment is saved to the folder. Please  check my  code to understand what the heck I am talking about.

```
#region Get External Attachments
requestMessage = service.Users.Messages.Get("me", messageId);
Message attMessage = requestMessage.Execute();
IList<MessagePart> parts = attMessage.Payload.Parts;
foreach (MessagePart p in parts)
{
    if (p.Filename.Length > 0 && p.Filename != null)
    {
        string attid = p.Body.AttachmentId;

        if (attid != null)
        {
            MessagePartBody attachPart = service.Users.Messages.Attachments.Get("me", messageId, attid).Execute();

           byte[] data = FromBase64ForUrlString(attachPart.Data);

           string decodedString = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
           var dir = @"G:\" + messageId;
           Console.WriteLine("FileName:"+" "+p.Filename);
           // Console.WriteLine("MimeType:"+p.MimeType+"  "+p.Filename);
            if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
                File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(dir, p.Filename), data);
            }
        }
    }
}
#endregion
```

I have tested the above code with a mail with three attachments (jpg, excel file, and pdf), here jpg is the first attachment, it's the only attachment, which is saved in the folder. I want to save all attachment  files to the folder.

```
Console.WriteLine("FileName:"+" "+p.Filename);
```

the above line returns the names of all attachments but my code is not saving them. Where did I go wrong?

**Updated:**

```
 if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
                    {

                        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
                       // File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(dir, p.Filename), data);
                    }
                    File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(dir, p.Filename), data);
```

after  changing my code with above lines , everything works like a charm.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the API you are using? And maybe a few more code from your email access, in order for us to check locally before submitting an answer

Comment: Look at your `if` statement. You save the file only when the directory does not exist. I think, this question should be closed, since the error does not belong to GMail API.

Comment: Soon, you are right. Just a small mistake , I figured it out myself but was too late to edit the question. :P thanks anyway. You have sharp eyes.

Comment: thanks , Nicolas for taking interest in helping me. it was just a "If" mistake.

Comment: Nicely re-usable piece of code...

Answer (score 0):

// The missing function from the solution above

```
  public static byte[] FromBase64ForUrlString(string base64ForUrlInput)
        {
            int padChars = (base64ForUrlInput.Length % 4) == 0 ? 0 : (4 - (base64ForUrlInput.Length % 4));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(base64ForUrlInput, base64ForUrlInput.Length + padChars);
            result.Append(String.Empty.PadRight(padChars, '='));
            result.Replace('-', '+');
            result.Replace('_', '/');
            return Convert.FromBase64String(result.ToString());
        }
```